# How to protect php program folder with password in www folder

Tags: php, passwords, directory

I checked this Links..

[Protect folder with password fails on localhost (under Apache and Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390978/protect-folder-with-password-fails-on-localhost-under-apache-and-windows)

in this the solution is to execute the project using a password but i only want to protect php program folder from direct access.

I don't want password authentication while php program execution.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file in the directory which you want to protect from direct access. The .htaccess file contains the following code: Options -Indexes

Comment: Sir, please elaborate, idon't know much about htaccess file

Comment: Sure, a .htaccess file is a config file for use on web servers running Apache. When you put a .htaccess file in a directory (in your case the directory which you want to protect), the .htaccess file gets detected and executed by Apache web server (www.htaccess-guide.com)

Comment: It's as easy as opening a new file in e.g. notepad, enter: Options -Indexes and save the file in the directory you want to protect as .htaccess (do not forget the leading period '.' in .htaccess)

Comment: Sir, i have done this, but now also any one can edit my code..but i don't want that happen, Could you please give a solution for this.

Comment: Hi, add the following to your .htaccess file: `deny from all` this should bar access to any file in the directory.